multiple definition of ..., all in the same line
Makefile:
CC          := clang
CFLAGS      := 
PROJECT_DIR := $(shell pwd)
CFLAGS      += -I${PROJECT_DIR} #absolute include 

LDLIBS      := -lncurses

SRC         := src
HEADER      := inc
OBJ         := obj
SRCs        := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)           # must be replaced with bash "ls" command, for recursive search
HEADERs     := $(wildcard $(HEADER)/*.h)        # must be replaced with bash "ls" command, for recursive search

HeaderSbfix := hdr

OBJs        := main.o
OBJs        += $(patsubst $(HEADER)/%.h,$(HEADER)/%.o, $(HEADERs))
OBJs        += $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c, $(SRC)/%.o, $(SRCs)) 

BIN         := a.out

# default command in "make" 
all: $(BIN)


$(BIN): $(OBJs) $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJs) $(LDLIBS) 


$(SRC)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -c $<  $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)  -o $@

$(HEADER)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -c $<  $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)  -o $@

$(OBJ):
    mkdir -p $@


clean:
    rm -r $(OBJs)
    rm $(BIN)

file structure:
project
|
| - main.c
| - Makefile
|
| - | src
    - snake.c
    - graphics.c
| - | inc
    - snake.h
    - graphics.h

Error (part of it):
/usr/bin/ld: src/snake.o: in function `direction_changed':
snake.c:(.text+0x200): multiple definition of `direction_changed'; inc/snake.o:snake.c:(.text+0x200): first defined here

All the symbols in the snake.c source file are causing a linker error.
There is no recursive include.
There is no  definition in the header file, only struct and function declarations.
I'm suspecting the makefile.
The last output of the makefile:
clang -o a.out -I/home/noirangel/prog/snake-in-terminal  main.o inc/graphics.o inc/snake.o  src/graphics.o  src/snake.o  -lncurses 


The line OBJs += $(patsubst $(HEADER)/%.h,$(HEADER)/%.o, $(HEADERs)) in your makefile looks wrong.  Why would you associate a .o with a .h file?

The result of the above is that inc/snake.o and src/snake.o are generated from src/snake.c and contain the same code: hence the multiple definitions.  I'd imagine the same holds for inc/graphics.o and src/graphics.o.

thank you, I was so focused for every compilation unit to have an obj file that contains its symbols, that I literally forgot the existence of the preprocessor, and the #include

When you get linker errors the first thing to do is carefully examine the link command line and look for mistakes, not look at the makefile.  Only once you discover what's wrong with the linker command line, will it be useful to go look in the makefile and figure out how that mistake happened.
